# How to get position of comment ( // ,/* or */ ) in a line via regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line of c++ code in an array:

```
@code="$_";
```

Now I have to get whether this line contain comment or not. That I can do by checking:

```
if( @code=~'/*')
```

or

```
if(@code=~m{//}
```

But there can be a situation like:

```
cout<<"welcome";/*this is just to print*/
```

Here our line is not full comment.

For this kind of situation I am getting stuck. Please help me.

Comment: You'll have to use a stricter pattern right? See here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions

Comment: Can you try and prepare an example in Regex101.com ?

Comment: If the code has `cout<<"http://www.some.com";` `if(@code=~m{//}` will show a false positive. Try just `/^\h*\/\//` and `/^\h*\/\*/`. However, `/*` marks a multiline comment - but I guess you only want to find a line that contains its start, right? Note that a regex for a multiline comment is `/\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//`, if you need to find them at the start of the string, just prepend with `^\h*`.

Comment: Why is the line in an array?? Are the items in the array individual characters, or is there a single scalar member which contains the line? The natural and idiomatic way to handle a line of input is to read it into a scalar variable (`$_` by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From perlfaq6:

[How do I use a regular expression to strip C-style comments from a file?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file)

```
$/ = undef;
$_ = <>;
s#/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)#defined $2 ? $2 : ""#gse;
print;
```

This could, of course, be more legibly written with the /x modifier, adding whitespace and comments. Here it is expanded, courtesy of Fred Curtis.

```
s{
   /\*         ##  Start of /* ... */ comment
   [^*]*\*+    ##  Non-* followed by 1-or-more *'s
   (
     [^/*][^*]*\*+
   )*          ##  0-or-more things which don't start with /
               ##    but do end with '*'
   /           ##  End of /* ... */ comment

 
 |         ##     OR  various things which aren't comments:

 
   (
     "           ##  Start of " ... " string
     (
       \\.           ##  Escaped char
     |               ##    OR
       [^"\\]        ##  Non "\
     )*
     "           ##  End of " ... " string

 
   |         ##     OR

 
     '           ##  Start of ' ... ' string
     (
       \\.           ##  Escaped char
     |               ##    OR
       [^'\\]        ##  Non '\
     )*
     '           ##  End of ' ... ' string

 
   |         ##     OR

 
     .           ##  Anything other char
     [^/"'\\]*   ##  Chars which doesn't start a comment, string or escape
   )
 }{defined $2 ? $2 : ""}gxse;
```

A slight modification also removes C++ comments, possibly spanning multiple lines using a continuation character:

```
s#/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//([^\\]|[^\n][\n]?)*?\n|("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|'(\\.|[^'\\])*'|.[^/"'\\]*)#defined $3 ? $3 : ""#gse;
```

---

You can try CPAN module [Regexp::Common::comment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::comment):

> Please consult the manual of Regexp::Common for a general description of the works of this interface.
>
> Do not use this module directly, but load it via [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common).
>
> This modules gives you regular expressions for comments in various languages.
>
> > The C++ language has two forms of comments. Comments that start with `//` and last till the end of the line, and comments that start with `/*`, and end with `*/`. If `{-keep}` is used, only `$1` will be set, and set to the entire comment.